# C++ access set via iterator

Tags: c++, set

I have the following code:

```
struct voxel
{
    int x, y, z;
};
std::set<std::set<voxel>> regions;

std::set<std::set<voxel>>::iterator regions_it;
std::set<voxel>::iterator voxel_it;
for (regions_it = regions.begin(); regions_it != regions.end(); regions_it++){
    for (voxel_it = regions_it->begin(); voxel_it != regions_it->end; voxel_it++){
         if (condition){
             struct voxel v = { 1, 2, 3 };
             regions_it->insert(v);
         }
    }
}
```

Just assume that "condition" is a boolean. I have trouble specifically with `regions_it->insert(v)`. The arrow (->) is marked as error. I tried with `regions_it.insert(v)` but it doesn't work either.

`regions_it` should be a pointer that points to a set of voxels if I'm not mistaken, but how can I call the insert method?

I'm still unfamiliar to C++. Would be nice if someone can help me out.

Comment: What error do you get exactly? "Marked as error" does not tell us much.

Comment: Why did you edit the question to match the answer? How is someone supposed to see what the problem was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have braces around:

```
if (condition)
             struct voxel v = { 1, 2, 3 };
             regions_it->insert(v);
```

so v is out of scope when you try to use it.

You also didn't put parenthesis on  end here:

```
    for (voxel_it = regions_it->begin(); voxel_it != regions_it->end; voxel_it++){
```

However, the main problem is that you cannot change the elements in a set, as they are used for sorting the contents of the set and if you changed them directly, the set may no longer function as intended.  Because of that, dereferencing an iterator on a set returns a `const` reference to its contents.  A `const std::set` doesn't have an `insert` method.

Comment: Hello, first of all sorry for those syntax errors, I didn't want to copy the whole code to make the problem unnecessarily complex. Thank you for your answer. I guess, the answer would be, using Lists instead?

Comment: The short answer is "use vector everywhere".  From a performance perspective, pretty much every other STL container is awful.  List would work, if you don't care about performance, but you saying voxel makes me think you may.

Comment: Watch out for iterator invalidation, though.   Any type of modification with a vector will invalidate all your iterators and pointers into it.  That is one reason that lists are a bit easier to use (but you still shouldn't)

Comment: Alright, that's a lot of tips, I'll try out both variants, thank you very much.

Comment: @Broccoli I really suggest becoming VERY familiar and confident with std::vector and ignoring the rest -- most painfully, std::map.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using **list** instead of **set** (and push_back() instead of insert()) works.

But please note, that in general it is not a good idea to modify the collections you are iterating.  It can lead to very nasty bugs.  Generally it's a good idea to create the result of the iteration in a new data structure, and copy it over at the end.

Another remark is that in your example you are not using the second, inner loop at all.